# How to share external links or URLs on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to write application that will be sending links to facebook fanpage wall.
I use a PHP SDK v3. There is a example how to post stuff:

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXX',
    'secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYY',
    'cookie' => true,
));
$fbsession = $facebook->getSession();

    if ($fbsession) {
       $attachment = array(
          'message' => 'this is my message',
          'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
          'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
          'link' => 'http://www.lycos.com',
          'description' => 'Test de post depuis application PHP',
          'picture' => 'http://www.lalibre.be/img/logoLaLibre.gif',
          'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
          'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
      );
     $result = $facebook->api('/USER_WALL/feed/','post',$attachment);
  }
```

and it works fine. The problem is I want to post just a normal facebook-link (with link icon, without application name and with Share button)

something like this:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/USER_WALL/feed/','link',$attachment);

gives me an error (Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unsupported method, link thrown in /home/.../src/base_facebook.php on line 959)
```

any ideas how to do this?
I found two links to FB Documentation:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.post/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

but I still don't know use this in PHP-SDK v3

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.post/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

Comment: can you copy/paste me the code when you are retrieving access_toekn please? thanks

Comment: set permissions using this link:
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,read_stream,manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` 
it will return CODE, use it in the next link: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=APP_SECRET&code=CODE`
it will return access_token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
    $attachment = array(
        'access_token'=>TOKEN,
        'message'=>'message_here',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
    );
    $result = $facebook->api(
        'me/links',
        'post',
        $attachment
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this example on this website. Its a full implementation of the status update and posting technique on a users wall. [LINK TO THE TUTORIAL](http://wizardsoweb.com/graph-api-how-to-post-status-updates-complete-example/2011/05/)

**EDIT AFTER READING THE COMMENTS**

Use the following url to share custom links:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.YourUrlThatYouWantToShare.com
```

Comment: did you check the link's post properly? the site also features posts for creating applications that can post in offline mode.

Comment: hope you deleted the comment you posted earlier. anyways, can you please tell me what problem are you still facing?

Comment: Yes. I saw this link. I think it still doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am asking about the problem that you are still facing. Can you tell me more on the problem?

Comment: please check this: http://bit.ly/mA2O24 -- Is it possible to post with PHP-SDK the second link (with green text)?

Comment: yes, i just want to post URL's that doesn't contain my application name and have Share button

Comment: check the edited answer. just create a GET request or make an hyperlink to the url mentioned in the answer and change the url with the actual url you want to share.

Comment: ok, but I need to do this without being a user logged in facebook. This must be done by application with offline_access and link must appear on one of my fanpage.

Comment: if you are sharing from applications that have offline_access enabled, then my buddy, facebook doesnt allow the app to hide its name from the post. Facebook manually and forcefully puts it on the post like `via YourAppName`

Comment: : ) ok, I can live with this. but why on facebook developer docs there is a post: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ and link reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/ ... what is this LINK?! O_o. other quiestion is how to add Share button to my posts.

Comment: simply by hyperlinking the button or text link to the updated answer's link.

Comment: I wonder if I can just modify $attachment that "Share" button will appear in the footer. I will check this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hello there again! "if you are sharing from applications that have offline_access enabled, then my buddy, facebook doesnt allow the app to hide its name from the post. Facebook manually and forcefully puts it on the post like via YourAppName – Coding-Freak May 26 at 16:12". I have to disagree with you. $facebook->api('/me/links/','post',$attachment); works in offline_access and it's posting a links with share button without app name - what is finally solving my problem

Comment: @erroid : Then i guess there is something wrong with the api. Because this same code didnt work for me earlier.